# The onchange htmlattribute won't pass a model property to the js function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, asp.net-core, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to take user input from the dropdown list in the partial view and pass it into the js function in the index page to filter out results based on the value of the QuestionType property.
So, a view model looks like this:

```
public class TestQuestionModel
    {
        public Guid TestId { get; set; }

        public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    }
```

Dropdown list in the razor page looks like this:

```
@model ICollection<Lab.Quiz.BL.Services.TestCardService.Models.TestQuestionModel>
...    
@Html.DropDownList("QuestionType", new SelectListItem[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Single Selection Question", Value = "SingleSelectionQuestion", Selected = true},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Multiple Answers Question", Value = "MultipleAnswerQuestion"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Open Answer Question", Value = "OpenAnswerQuestion"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Program Code Question", Value = "ProgramCodeQuestion"}
                },
                    new
                    {
                        onchange = "filterQuestions('{@Model.FirstOrDefault()?.TestId.ToString()}', this.value)"
                    })
```

And the function on the index page looks like this:

```
function filterQuestions(testId, questionType) {
        alert("called");
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/Filter",
            data: { testId: testId, questionType: questionType },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#questionsDiv").html(result);
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately, the function won't be called. However, if I change the function to only accept one attribute and accordingly change the function call to only include one attribute (*this.value*), it works as intended.
Any suggestions on how to pass from the @Html.DropdownList not only its value, but also a property of the model?

Comment: Can you check the generated HTML result and post it, maybe something is wrong in that syntax?

Comment: I did so far replace HTML helper with raw HTML code and managed to pass both the selected option value and the testId to the controller. Problem must be with syntax I used in the htmlhelper, namely in ... onchange = "filterQuestions('{@Model.FirstOrDefault()?.TestId.ToString()}', this.value)"

Comment: Sure the problem is in this syntax. Check in your browser, check the generated <select> element, you will probably see the syntax error there.

Comment: @Razr_Max Do you have any problems with my post? If you have question, feel free to ask. And if it can help, you can accept as an answer, so it can help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, use **+...+** to split the data:

```
onchange = "filterQuestions("+@Model.FirstOrDefault().TestId.ToString()+", this.value)"
```

Result:

[image]